# Como sumar subelementos de un diccionario

Tags: python-3.x

Deseo poder sumar las poblaciones solo de los paises que sean de asia... como puedo hacerlo teniendo en cuenta este diccionario, el ejemplo real que tengo es con mas datos pero este es suficiente para escalarlo.
He intentado esto pero me sale none.

```
dicionario={'pais':['Peru','China','Israel','india'],
            'region':['sudamerica','asia','asia','asia'],
            'poblacion':[30,1300,40,1100]}

for i,j in dicionario.items():
    if i=='region':
        if j=='asia':
            suma=0
            for k in j:
                suma=suma+k
```

Comment: ¿Y has intentado algo? en caso afirmativo, agrégalo a tu pregunta para que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

En el fondo tienes tres listas paralelas guardadas en un diccionario:

```
dicionario={'pais':['Peru','China','Israel','india'],
            'region':['sudamerica','asia','asia','asia'],
            'poblacion':[30,1300,40,1100]}

lista_region = dicionario['region']
lista_poblacion = dicionario['poblacion']
```

por tanto, extraigamos la lista y olvidemosnos del diccionario.

Con tres listas paralelas, forzamente debes recorrerarlas por indice, pues con el índice de una puedes acceder al dato correspondiente en la otra.

```
poblacion = 0
for i in range(len(lista_region)):
    if lista_region[i] == 'asia':
        poblacion += lista_poblacion[i]

print(f"Poblacion: {poblacion}")
```

produce:

```
Poblacion: 2440

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Una mejor alternativa**

El problema está mal modelado. Lo correcto sería crear una clase `Pais` que una los datos nombre, región, población en un solo objeto:

```
class Pais:
    def __init__(self, pais, region, poblacion):
        self.pais = pais
        self.region = region
        self.poblacion = poblacion
```

Así los datos quedan amarrados unos con otros, sin posibilidad de confusión ni maniobras raras para acceder a ellos.

Ahora construyo una lista de países:

```
paises = [Pais("Peru", "Sudamerica", 30),
          Pais("China", "Asia", 1300),
          Pais("Israel", "Asia", 40),
          Pais("India", "Asia", 1100)
          ]
```

y operaciones como la pedida se vuelven tribiales:

```
poblacion = sum(p.poblacion for p in paises)
print(f"Población: {poblacion}")
```

BTW, Israel es un país del Medio Oriente, no de Asia.

Comment: graciasss... mano, solo una pequeña obs... Medio oriente esta en Asia

Comment: Aunque técnicamente correcto, las gentes de la región se identifican a si mismos como "medio oriente".